# Перегрузка оператора +=

Tags: c++, строки, классы, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор

```
// Реализовать класс String  для работы со строками. Перегрузить операторы = + += - > < [] (подстрока) ++ --
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String
{


    char* s;
    int length;

public:


    String(const char* str="")
    {
        this->length = strlen(str);
        this->s = new char[this->length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        this->s[i] = str[i];
    }


    String(const String& s1)
    {
        this->length = s1.length;
        this->s = new char[this->length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
            this->s[i] = s1.s[i];
    }


    ~String()
    {
         delete[] s;
    }



String& String::operator=(String& right);
    String String::operator+(String right);
    //String& String::operator+=(const String& right);
    friend String& operator+=(String& left, const String& right);
    void String::show();

};
```

А это цпп файл:

```
#include "String.h"

void String::show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        cout << this->s[i];
}


String& String::operator=(String& right)
{
    delete[] this->s;
    this->length = right.length;
    this->s = new char[this->length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        this->s[i] = right.s[i];
    return *this;
}

String String::operator+(String right)
{
    String new_string;
    new_string.length = this->length + right.length;
    new_string.s =new char[this->length + right.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        new_string.s[i] = this->s[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
        new_string.s[this->length + i] = right.s[i];
    return new_string;
}

String& operator+=(String& left, const String& right)
{
    return left+right;
}
```

Почему у меня s3 всё равно при выводе пустая? Помогите начинающему!

```
#include "String.h"

void main()
{
    String s2("Hello");
    String s3;
    s3 += s2;
    s3.show();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Начнем с того, что вам следует включить заголовок `<cstring>`

```
#include <cstring>
```

так как вы используете функции, объявленные в этом заголовке.

Длину строки лучше определять, как имеющую тип `size_t` вместо `int`.

```
class String
{
    char* s;
    size_t length;
    //...
```

Ваши конструкторы неверно копируют строки. Они не копируют в результирующую строку завершающий символ нуля `'\0'`. Например,

```
String(const char* str="")
{
    this->length = strlen(str);
    this->s = new char[this->length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    // символ нуля не входи в диапазон `[0, length)`
    this->s[i] = str[i];
}
```

Иначе непонятно, зачем вы выделяете память длиною `this->length+1` вместо `this->length`.
Непонятно, зачем вы вообще используете циклы для копирования строк, когда вы уже используете стандартные C функции из заголовка `<cstring>`

Лучше было бы объявить конструктор следующим образом

```
String( const char *str = "" )
{
    this->length = std::strlen( str );
    this->s = new char[ this->length + 1 ];
    std::strcpy( this->s, str );
}
```

То же самое замечание справедливо и для конструктора копирования.

В определении класса нельзя указывать квалифицированное имя функций-членов класса при их объявлении. Хотя `MS VC++` это допускает, но это является его собственным расширением языка, которое не соответствует стандарту.

```
String& String::operator=(String& right);
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Эти объявления

```
String String::operator+(String right);
friend String& operator+=(String& left, const String& right);
```

лучше переопределить следующим образом

```
friend String operator + ( const String &left, const String &right );
String & operator += ( const String &right );
```

Функцию `show` лучше объявить как

```
std::ostream & String::show( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const;
```

Переопределите соответствующие функции с учетом выше приведенных замечаний.

Что касается копирующего оператора присваивания, то он может быть определен следующим образом

```
String & String::operator =( const String &right )
{
    if ( this != &right )
    {
        size_t n = std::strlen( right.s );
        char tmp = new char[ n + 1 ];

        std::strcpy( tmp, right.s );

        delete [] this->s;

        this->s = tmp;
        this->length = n;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Аналогичным образом вам нужно определить оператор

```
String & operator += ( const String &right );
```

Например

```
String & String::operator +=( const String &right )
{
    size_t n = this->length + std::strlen( right.s );
    char tmp = new char[ n + 1 ];

    std::strcpy( tmp, this->s );
    std::strcat( tmp, right.s );

    delete [] this->s;

    this->s = tmp;
    this->length = n;

    return *this;
}
```

Функция `show` определяется просто

```
std::ostream & String::show( std::ostream &os ) const
{
    return os << this->s;
}
```

Что касается вашего вопроса

```
Почему у меня s3 всё равно при выводе пустая?
```

то этот оператор

```
String& operator+=(String& left, const String& right)
{
    return left+right;
}
```

не изменяет левый аргумент. И более того имеет неопределенное поведение, так как возвращает ссылку на временный объект, создаваемый выражением `left+right`.

EDIT: Если оператор operator [], который, как я понимаю, вы также должны определить, позволяет вставлять в объект класса символ `'\0'`, то вам следует изменить определения конструктора копирования, копирующего опреатора присваивания, оператора `operator +=`, и дружественной функции `operator +`, заменив стандартные C функции `strXXX` на `memXXX`. Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как это можно сделать на примере некоторых членов класса. Другие члены класса постарайтесь определить сами.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class String
{
private:
    char *s;
    size_t length;

public:
    String( const char *str = "" )
    {
        this->length = std::strlen( str );
        this->s = new char[ this->length + 1 ];

        std::strcpy( this->s, str );
    }

    String( const String &src )
    {
        this->length = src.length;
        this->s = new char[ this->length + 1 ];

        std::memcpy( this->s, src.s, this->length + 1 );
    }

    String & operator =( const String &src )
    {
        if ( this !=+ &src )
        {
            char *tmp = new char[ src.length + 1 ];

            std::memcpy( tmp, src.s, src.length + 1 );

            delete [] this->s;

            this->s = tmp;
            this->length = src.length;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    String & operator +=( const String &src )
    {
        size_t n = this->length + src.length;
        char *tmp = new char[ n + 1 ];

        std::memcpy( tmp, this->s, this->length );
        std::memcpy( tmp + this->length, src.s, src.length + 1 );

        delete [] this->s;

        this->s = tmp;
        this->length = n;

        return *this;

    }

    ~String()
    {
        delete [] this->s;
    }

    std::ostream & show( std::ostream &os = std::cout )
    {
        return os << this->s;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    String s1( "Hello world!" );
    String s2;

    s2 = s1;

    s2.show() << std::endl;

    s2 += " Glad to see you!";

    s2.show() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы будет следующим

```
Hello world!
Hello world! Glad to see you!
```

Comment: Благодарю, ваш ответ действительно был полезным! :)

Comment: @Никита Я подправил определение следующего оператора, так как у меня была опечатка и возвращаемый тип не был ссылкой String & String::operator +=( const String &right ). То есть возвращаемый тип должен быть String &.

Comment: @Никита Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.:)